# google sheet email alert if expiry date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table with 8 columns with dates. I need to track them if they are to expire, but for 3 of them I need to alert alert 3 months before and for the remaining columns, 6 months before.

I think that I am on the right track with the code below, but still not doing what it needs to be done.

I start with one month in the beginning. Can somebody help me?

```
function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  var newToday = new Date()
  var oneMonthFromToday = new Date(newToday.setMonth(newToday.getMonth()+1));
  var oneMonthMonth = oneMonthFromToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var oneMonthDay = oneMonthFromToday.getDate();
  var oneMonthYear = oneMonthFromToday.getFullYear();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = 100; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];

    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[6]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );
    var subject = '';
    var message = ' You have expiring pass. ' + '\n';
    MailApp.sendEmail('lubomira.petkova88@gmail.com', subject, message);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet? What you need here is a properly set trigger. Daily trigger should do it and have your time on your date values set to 00:00:00.

Comment: Hi, i don't need time i need to remove it. Also here is the link of sample:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12sMuvAP8A-t3wbjsNpRM0PY6hk9H2Dk2bkCI7mkwl1o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you have it public @Lubomira Petkova?

Comment: yep,sorry now its public

Comment: can you also include here what columns are needed to be seen for the exact date, 3 months and 6 months?

Comment: I update them in the 1st raw after the N of the pass

Comment: Hi @Lubomira, please join here for more info: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228010/room-65957615

Comment: Sorry but i can't : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear on your post but the code below assumed only 1 column needs to be checked. Feel free to adjust the conditions but this should be the main idea of your code.

**Code:**

```
function checkPasswordExpiry() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // 3 months before
  var prev3Months = new Date();
  prev3Months.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 3);
  prev3Months.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // 6 months before
  var prev6Months = new Date();
  prev6Months.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 6);
  prev6Months.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  // get number of rows/columns in sheet instead of manually setting it
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numCols);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];

    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[6]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );

    var date = new Date(row[6]);
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    
    var subject = 'Password Expiry';
    var message = 'Hi ' + row[0] + ', \nYour password is expiring';
    var email = 'lubomira.petkova88@gmail.com';

    if(date.getTime() === prev6Months.getTime()) {
      message += " in 6 months. ( " + expireDateFormat + " )";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
    else if(date.getTime() === prev3Months.getTime()) {
      message += " in 3 months. ( " + expireDateFormat + " )";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
    else if(date.getTime() === today.getTime()) {
      message += " today. ( " + expireDateFormat + " )";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

The code above does check column G whether it is already 6 months before today, 3 months before today or exactly the date. If you need to check multiple columns, just replace the conditions inside and it should still work.

**Sample email:**

[image: sample output]

Note that the code above should be triggered every day so it can check the data daily.

**Code:**

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkPasswordExpiry')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(0)
      .create();
}
```

Function `createTimeDrivenTriggers` needs to be run just once. Please see reference below.

**Reference:**

- [Time driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
- [everyDays()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everydaysn)

If I wasn't able to provide you the answer you are hoping for, I sincerely apologize. Feel free to comment below what are the changes that are needed to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately i cant enter in the chat room to explain. I dont receive the emails .... Can i send you an email?

Comment: There was an issue on my previous answer. I updated the answer, can you try it again? @LubomiraPetkova.

Comment: Hi, no still do not receive emails ( i test it to change the date in G but still nothing) You asked me what are the meanings of the columns – I have 25 employees and each and every have badges for specific areas in the building. Those are the 3 months before that I need to see and the last one is passport expiry date which I need to know 7m before. I don’t need time and today .

Comment: Hi @LubomiraPetkova, I'm sorry if it didn't worked on yours. You might need to debug it on your side, check where the code ends, what values are being compared and show the errors here so we can help. It might just have some column/data issues or something we weren't able to consider. It might also be a code issue, but we can't make sure unless it is being debugged on your side.  Thoroughly investigate where the error starts and what causes it.

Comment: Hi NaziA , so i change couple of things and for now is working. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: no problem @LubomiraPetkova, glad to be of help. If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer